# how to create a pop up in mvc 4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, i want to show a pop up when deleting a row from my table, **so this is my action link :**

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.cin  },new { @class = "delete-logo"  ,@pkNo=item.cin})
 <div id="confirmDialog" title="Warning"></div>
```

**my script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    buttonizeALL();
    setLinks();
});

function buttonizeALL() 
{        
    $(".delete-logo").button();
}

function setLinks() 
{
    //delete person
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".delete-logo").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var pkNo = $(this).attr("pkNo");


            $("#confirmDialog").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 300,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        var rowNo = '#row-' + pkNo;
                        var url = '/Subscribers/Delete/' + pkNo;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "Delete",
                            url: url,
                            data: {},
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function () {

                                $(rowNo).animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 400, function () {
                                    $(rowNo).remove();
                                });

                            },

                            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                            }

                        }); //end ajax call

                    }, // end of yes button
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                } //end buttons
            }); //end modal 
        });      //end delete

    });
} //end setLinks
```

my problem is the pop up doesn't work, and when i used my script without the pop up it works, so please if some one have any idea i will be very appreciated.

Comment: I think the code line `new { id = "ed" }` should be like this `new { @id = "ed" }`

Comment: try this one `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { @id = "ed", @class = "delete-logo", @pkNo = "ed" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rmPQ6) is your example tidied up a little in a jsFiddle i.e. I've moved the setLinks() code into the document.ready() function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    buttonizeALL();
    setLinks(); // removed this
});
```

Also I've replaced the ActionLink with the anchor tag it will render.
This is using Jquery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2. The pop-up seams to work fine.

Comment: Can you tell the meaning of e.preventDefault() in this `$(".delete-logo").live("click", function (e) {` ?

Comment: The `e.preventDefault()` was copied from the original question's JavaScript. The normal use of this method is to prevent the default event of clicking the '.delete-logo' anchor from being triggered.

Comment: thanks wellers, i test it it works for a simple link (<a class="delete-logo" href="#">Delete</a>) but it still not working with  my actionlink

Comment: The problem could be with the ActionLink then. What values does your `item.cin` take?

Comment: Testing this locally I have got an ActionLink like this `<a class="delete-logo ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" href="/Flow/Delete/1" pkNo="1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span></a>`. It seems to work for me although I am using jquery-ui-1.10.2. Ensure you have got both the JQuery UI script files and css added to your _Layout.cs.

Comment: @wellers how it can be clicked by default ?

Comment: @wellers can u please give me the jquery-ui-1.10.2 script and css

Comment: I installed it using NuGet. It's available from [here](http://nuget.org/packages/jquery.ui.combined/) or directly from JQuery [here](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 1):

first off, don't use "live" command anymore.  Thats been deprecated in lieu of the "on" command.  Also there is no need to use the $(document).ready within the setLinks function.  Since its a standalone function (not self executing) its only put into memory until its called when you call it in the doc.ready function.